Thinkpad T460 Shutdown/Suspend in Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Thinkpad T460 with Intel I7 and 16 GB of RAM. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch using the new installer with automated minimal installation with all codecs and proprietary drivers. I have all firmware updates up to date. I installed using Safe Mode and UEFI. I updated all the libraries to the newest ones. I have currently two problems: with 1) shutdown/suspend mode; 2) and Bluetooth. This post is about 1) Shutdown/suspend.
When I command via GUI or via terminal for the computer to shut down, the desktop performs all the required commands, the screen gets black, all the LEDs stop and the fan stop spinning, but the laptop is still consuming energy. Then the battery depletes the system is indeed shut down for good. If I press the power button in this state, the computer does not respond. I must force shut down by pressing the power button for a few seconds and then I am able to restart the system.
When I close the lid, the laptop goes in suspend mode, the LED from the power button blinks slowly, but the system does not wake up then I fast/long press the power button; press any other key in the keyboard; or try to enter terminal mode.
None of these issues appeared in Ubuntu 23.10. Theses issues do not appear in Fedora 40 as well.
Im no Linux expert and know only the basics of the terminal at the moment, but Im not afraid to run any command if needed.
Someone know how to fix this issues or need more detail? I appreciate the help.
Best Regards.

This Redit thread has the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/t03sd2/fresh_install_on_t460_laptop_wont_wake_after/
Quoting:

Set intel_iommu=off on the kernel command line.
How to add a kernel parameter in grub2
How do I add a kernel boot parameter?
Bug report : https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197029

